# Adicionar dados na array() em PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um carrinho em PHP, porém, na hora de adicionar itens a array, não estou conseguindo, eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
if($this->session->userdata('cart')==true){
    if(count($this->session->userdata('cart'))==0){
        $i = 0;
    } else {
        $i = count($this->session->userdata('cart'))+1;
    } 
    foreach($this->session->userdata('cart') as $value){
        $data[$i] = array(
            'cart_type' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? 'purchase' : 'order',
            'product_id' => $this->input->post('product_id'),
            'stock_purchase' => $this->input->post('stock_purchase'),
            'stock_unity_push' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? $this->input->post('stock_unity_push') : '0',
            'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'),
        );
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    $data[] = array(
        'cart_type' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? 'purchase' : 'order',
        'product_id' => $this->input->post('product_id'),
        'stock_purchase' => $this->input->post('stock_purchase'),
        'stock_unity_push' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? $this->input->post('stock_unity_push') : '0',
        'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'),
    );
}
```

O problema é que, cada vez que eu incluo um novo item na array, ele substitui, e não adiciona. Como eu consigo apenas adicionar itens?

Obs: Estou usando o codeigniter para renderizar.

Comment: Já tentou montar seu array primeiro e depois inserir ele?

Comment: Ainda não... ....

Comment: Faça isso, e utilize `array_push` ao invés de só **=** (desta forma você vai recriar toda hora o array)

Comment: `Printa` o valor de $i pra ter certeza que ele está mudando

Answer (score 4):

André, pelo o que entendi você quer adicionar elementos ao final do vetor e da forma que você esta fazendo você sobrescreve o array.Para adicionar elementos ao final do vetor existe o método [push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php).

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de recriar o `array` apenas utilize o `array_push()`, sendo assim você terá certeza que será adicionado novos elementos.

```
array_push($data, array('cart_type' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? 'purchase' : 'order',
                  'product_id' => $this->input->post('product_id'),
                  'stock_purchase' => $this->input->post('stock_purchase'),
                  'stock_unity_push' => ($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')) ? $this->input->post('stock_unity_push') : '0',
                  'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier')));
```

Links úteis:
[array_push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php)